# angularjs http interceptor responseError object

Tags: angularjs, interceptor

I am getting below object by rejection.headers() function in `responseerror` object of interceptor but unable to get particular header value in angularjs code for example x-request-id value have to store in some variable but unable to do that can any one please suggest,

{pragma: "no-cache", date: "Thu, 06 Sep 2018 14:57:56 GMT", x-content-type-options: "nosniff", x-request-id: "VLCRpt3v", x-frame-options: "DENY", …}
cache-control
:
"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
content-type
:
"application/json;charset=UTF-8"
date
:
"Thu, 06 Sep 2018 14:57:56 GMT"
expires
:
"0"
pragma
:
"no-cache"
referrer-policy
:
"same-origin"
transfer-encoding
:
"chunked"
x-content-type-options
:
"nosniff"
x-frame-options
:
"DENY"
x-request-id
:
"VLCRpt3v"
x-xss-protection
:
"1; mode=block"

and trying below code in angularjs code : 
var head =  rejection.headers();
var requestId = head.x-request-id

Comment: Is this a cross-origin request?

Answer (score 2):

You'd better create an Interceptor and push it to to `$httpProvider` interceptor.

Here is what it should look like:

```
angular.module('app')
      .service('headerRetrieveInterceptor', function ($q) {
        var service = this;
        service.responseError = function (response) {
            // Here Are Your Headers
            console.log(response.headers());

            return $q.reject(response);
        };
    }).config(function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('headerRetrieveInterceptor');  
})
```